# Does the app wait for CommandLinerRunner run()'s subscriber(success,error) to execute or control returns to main thread after subscriber is registered

Tags: rest, tomcat, spring-webflux

In CommandLineRunner:

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iRedisCacheRepository.loadAllRuleGroups().subscribe(
        success -> redisResultSubscriber.accept(success),
        error -> redisErrorSubscriber.accept(error)
    );
}
```

When the rest API application with CommandLineRunner's `run()` is implemented which has `subscribe(success,error)` in it,
Does the application become available for rest api http requests only when `run()`'s subscriber (either success or error) is executed? or as `subscribe()` is *asynchronous* in nature, as soon as subscriber is registered, the control goes back to main thread and application becomes available for rest operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Mono/Flux publishes its result on a different thread (which is usually the case), then it does **NOT** wait.

You need to call `block()` if you want to wait for it.